# Three,js image texture to scale fit-center

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to fit images to picture frames and areas similar to them. Some frames work ok but generally I cannot fit the image right...this is the original image

[image]

This is what happens when I try to fit the image top the different frames/parts.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is my current code. As I said does work ok with picture frames that are similar to image size. But I try to do is to automatically scale and center to make image to different picture frame sizes/areas.

```
var texture = null; 
var material = null
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader() 
texture = await loader.load(media, async img => {  
    if(invertX) {
        texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
            texture.repeat.x = - 1; 
    }

    if(invertY) {
        texture.flipY = false;
    } 
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    });  
    elm.material = material;  
});
```

I tried different code without any success, placing below if any of them may help someone lead me somewhere

```
// const planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1,1)//(16, 9)   
// const planeAspect = planeGeom.parameters.width / planeGeom.parameters.height;
// const imageAspect = texture.image.width / texture.image.height; 
// const aspect = imageAspect / planeAspect;  

//doesnt work
// let imgRatio = img.image.width / img.image.height;
// let planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1,1)//16, 9) 
// let planeRatio = planeGeom.parameters.width / planeGeom.parameters.height; 
// texture.wrapS =  THREE.RepeatWrapping; // 
// texture.repeat.x = planeRatio / imgRatio;
// texture.offset.x = -0.5 * ((planeRatio / imgRatio) - 1);  

//this doesnt work as well
// const aspectOfPlane = planeGeom.parameters.width / planeGeom.parameters.height;
// const aspectOfImage = image.width / image.height;
// let yScale = 1;
// let xScale = aspectOfPlane / aspectOfImage;
// if (xScale > 1) { // it doesn't cover so based on x instead
// xScale = 1;
// yScale = aspectOfImage / aspectOfPlane;
// }
// texture.repeat.set(xScale, yScale);
// texture.offset.set((1 - xScale) / 2, (1 - yScale) / 2);

//this is another try
// var repeatX, repeatY;
// texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
// texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
// if (img.image.height < img.image.width) {
//   repeatX = planeGeom.parameters.width  * img.image.height / (planeGeom.parameters.height *img.image.width);
//   repeatY = 1;
//   texture.repeat.set(repeatX, repeatY);
//   texture.offset.x = (repeatX - 1) / 2 * -1;
// } else {
//   repeatX = 1;
//   repeatY = planeGeom.parameters.width * img.image.width / (planeGeom.parameters.height  * img.image.height);
//   texture.repeat.set(repeatX, repeatY);
//   texture.offset.y = (repeatY - 1) / 2 * -1;
// }
```

Comment: Please look into UV coordinates. These are percentage-based mappings that tell the material what point on the texture maps to what vertex on the model. Once you start working with them, you will see that you can even use them to center and scale the texture to fit the defined space.

Comment: but how? how do I calculate each for images? how do I use them for this situation?

Comment: chcek this article : [Fit image texture aspect ratio to size of plane](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/fit-image-texture-aspect-ratio-to-size-of-plane/27391)

Comment: I tried that article many times, that's why I'm asking here as the last resort and putting bounty on it